# Set focus on dropdown by select name with variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the focus of a dropdown using a variable in the select name=+variable+
My alert shows the correct name of the select to focus on but the focus doesn't get set. If I use the actual name of the select instead of the variable the focus works. I've looked at several examples and tried a mix of putting in " around the name but it still won't focus. Thanks for looking.

CSS

```
<style>
select:focus {
   background-color: yellow;
 }
</style>
```

JQuery

```
<script>

$('input[name^=dialsetting]').click(function () {

      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      var headtypenum = name.replace('dialsetting', 'headtype');

      alert(headtypenum);
      $('select[name=+headtypenum+]').focus();


    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<select name="headtype1">
    <option id="item37_0_option" selected value="1">Choose one</option>
    <option id="item37_1_option" value="A3">A3</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select name="headtype2">
    <option selected value="1">Choose one</option>
    <option value="A4">A4</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input name="dialsetting1" required type="number" />
<br>
<br>
<input name="dialsetting2" required type="number" />
```

Here's my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/progrower/3k4jv275/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you selector is wrong. change it to:

```
$('select[name=' + headtypenum + ']').focus();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3rnabfyp/)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I didn't try single quotes.LOL